# Двоеточие через каждые две цифры

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" id="postcode"/>
```

Есть input и надо, чтобы через каждые два символа ставилось автоматически двоеточие. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const pc = document.getElementById('postcode');

pc.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const v = e.target.value;
  pc.value = v.length ? v.replace(/:/g, '').match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':') : '';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="postcode" />
```

Comment: Хм, `v.replaceAll is not a function` свежий yandex.browser подводит)

Comment: Не, точно не доехало ещё из 85го хрома :(

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll Я за `.replace(/:/g, '')` =)

Comment: @vp_arth, действительно, забыл даже

Answer (score 0):

Если заранее известно количество двоеточий

```
<input  id="date" type="text"> 
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#date").mask("99:99:99:99");
});
</script>
```

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function` (¬_¬")

Comment: Требуется подключить библиотеку jquery

Comment: В стандартном jQuery нет такой функии, это должно быть какой-то плагин...